# What's the difference between getActiveRange() and getSelection()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

It seems like they both do the same thing, which is returning the selected range in an active "opened" sheet. What am I missing here? Are there cases where you need to use getSelection()?

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();    
var selection = sheet.getSelection();

// These return the same values
Logger.log("Range Values: %s", range.getValues());
Logger.log("Selection Values: %s", selection.getActiveRange().getValues());

// These also return the same values
Logger.log("Sheet Current Cell: %s", sheet.getCurrentCell().getValue());
Logger.log("Selection Current Cell: %s", selection.getCurrentCell().getValue());
```

Comment: According to the documentation, there is a difference. `getActiveRange()` returns the Class Range, but `getSelection()` returns the Class Selection.  The difference being that a selection ***can be non-adjacent ranges***.  So, if you need to get selected non-adjacent ranges, then you'd need to use `getSelection()`  A range can only be a "*group of adjacent cells in a sheet*"

Comment: @SandyGood Shouldn't this be an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, there is a difference.

`getActiveRange()` returns the Class Range, but `getSelection()` returns the Class Selection. The difference being that a selection can be non-adjacent ranges.

So, if you need to get selected non-adjacent ranges, then you'd need to use `getSelection()` A range can only be a "*group of adjacent cells in a sheet*"

Comment: So getSelection() is similar to getActiveRangeList()?

Comment: But how can you get the values of nonajacent range and leverage this property of selection class? Won't you need to append ```.getActiveRange().getValues()```? Which gets you to the constraints of getActiveRange() meaning that it's non-adjacent range again. A vicious circle.

Answer (score 0):

getActiveRangeList() seems to be actually needed to get non-adjacent ranges
in the end, it seems that we can use it with both of selection and active range.
thus there is no difference or why we use it until now to me imo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).